# How to fetch json api data in PWA?

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

In Angular project, I used JSON server to fetch dummy data. But currently I am trying to implement PWA in angular project. I am able to fetch static data . Also I want to display api response .
I am new to Angular. Please let me know How can I fetch json api response data in cache of browser and use in PWA?

Comment: There is no need to use cache of browser for PWA, @angular/pwa already handle it. just make a request and get response buddy!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [service workers](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro) and implement one of the [caching strategies](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker) per your intended use case (refer [service worker communications](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-communications) in angular).